# Spaces between button in Ant Design

Tags: css, antd

In https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design, how it the recommend method of adding spacing (margin) between buttons?

In semantic-ui, default margins defined within the library CSS. In bootstrap, one can use button groups to add spacing between buttons.

Is adding custom css or inline css the recommended way of achieving margins between buttons? Ideally, I want avoid writing any css when using a css framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use https://ant.design/components/space/ to put spaces between your buttons or any other elements.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that by simply wrapping your `<Button>` with `<Space>`

```
import { Button, Space } from 'antd';
<Space>
   <Button>Default</Button>
   <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
</Space>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two quick and dirty tricks

[image]

If you just want a tiny space in between, you can change

```
</Button><Button>
```

or

```
</Button>
<Button>
```

into

```
</Button> <Button>
```

[image]

and it will solve the problem

Alternatively put a `{' '}` in between, e.g. `</Button> {' '} <Button>`

Answer (score 0):

I use [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and components become really as components no global css, images and icons.

I define styles like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default styled.div`
    > button + button {
        margin-left: 16px;
    }
`
```

usually in a separate file for example: *Controls.js*

Then I use it as a component where it knows how to place the buttons (space between is 16px)

```
import React from 'react'
import Controls from './Controls'
import {Button} from 'antd'

export const Form = () =>
    <Controls>
        <Button type="primary" icon="check">
            Accpet
        </Button>
        <Button type="danger" icon="close">
            Cencel
        </Button>
    </Controls>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant design [grid system](https://ant.design/components/grid).

Then use `gutter` property for Row component. That will add spacing between grids.

Answer (score -1):

Put your buttons inside of a div. It will act as a button group.